# How to connect to a VirtualBox guest via host console

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

Is there a way to connect to a VirtualBox guest OS without the use of vrdp?

I have a VirtualBox test server that seems to halt somewhere during early boot, and I would like to connect to it from a terminal on the host in a similar fashion as vrdp. I don't have access to any GUI stuff on the host. Both the guest and the host are Ubuntu servers. Regular networking on the guest is not enabled by the time it halts.

EDIT: I ended up installing X on a related host, then used rdesktop in the usual fashion.

Comment: One possible workaround is if you have an X server on the system you are connecting from, you could always use `ssh -X` to connect to the host and then use X11 forwarding to use the VirtualBox GUI.

Comment: @sbtkd Which VBox GUI would that be? As it sits I have access to the VBoxManage tools, and rdesktop-vrdp .  rdesktop-vrdp gives me "Failed to  open display", i quite often use ssh -X to other systems where it works great.

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure of the exact command to invoke as I don't have an Ubuntu host with virtualbox installed, but I would think that `rdesktop-vrdp` or `virtualbox` should work.

Comment: I read you can start the virtual machine as 'headless' and then connect to it, but I haven't got it working myself yet: http://superuser.com/questions/442664/connect-to-a-headless-virtualbox-instance-in-linux

Answer (score 1):

from Linux, run below command:

```
  rdesktop-vrdp <host server name>:<virtual guest  VRDE Port number>
-u <user name> -p <password>
```

For example:

```
  rdesktop-vrdp onecloud:3800 -u cloud1 -p <password>
```